# how install wifi and bluetooth drivers for micromax ignite pc

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, bluetooth

Hi recently i installed Ubuntu latest release 16.04 i'm unable to detect my wifi and bluetooth .please let me know how install these drivers in my pc
previously i was using windows 10 i was able to use my Wifi and bluetooth drivers ...please  help me with solutions

```
avk123@avk123-Micromax-LPQ61408W-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for avk123: 
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:d5:9d:64:4b:86  
          inet addr:192.168.1.7  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7dfb:2f23:2394:2bce/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:117452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:171328168 (171.3 MB)  TX bytes:5137332 (5.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1053 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:106041 (106.0 KB)  TX bytes:106041 (106.0 KB)


avk123@avk123-Micromax-LPQ61408W-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: Please post the output of  sudo lshw -C network 
This will give more information, Lspci does not seem to show your Wifi-Adapter or Bluetooth Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Micromax ignite LPQ 61408W laptop too.

After a long ordeal I found that the laptop has RTL8723 chipset (Realtek). Since the company doesn't have any support for Linux, the drivers [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu) worked for me

Instructions on [this](http://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/~mittal/wifi.html) website helped a lot (make sure you change the URL and driver name in the steps).

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot...

Its still a bit buggy on my 16.10 but better than having nothing at all.

I am now hunting for Micro HDMI driver for the device. I will start a separate thread for it.